# geocoding, get corner latitude longitude

Tags: java, geocoding

I have some x/y point of an image, this points corresponds to latitude/longitude values, if I know the size of the image how to calculate(in java) image corners latitude/longitude?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

- take the scale
- check if lon at y  = l1 then what would it be at y = cornerY
- check if lat at x  = l1 then what would it be at x = corner

Comment: hi, I'm sorry but I don't understand... for example I have the following data: my image size is: 993x491 and I have this "calibration point":
calibrationId:001 imageX:285 imageY:94  latitude:45.46786607826646  longitude:9.182424545288086
calibrationId:002 imageX:959 imageY:101 latitude:45.468106853149656 longitude:9.193625450134277
calibrationId:003 imageX:163 imageY:214 latitude:45.46311056358185  longitude:9.182424545288086
                how to get lon/lat of point 0,0 or 993,491?   thanks